# Рандомное число, которое не должно совпадать с другими числами

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, случайные-числа, числа

Есть функция dorandom, которая вычисляет рандомное число от 0 до 8, которое не является числом в параметрах. Допустим: аргумент 4, результат любое рандомное число от 0 до 8, но не 4. Или аргумент 324, результат рандомное число от 0 до 8, но не 3, 2 или 4. Как это реализовать?

Comment: делаем список 0-8. из него убираем запретные числа и среди разрешённых выбираeм random.choice()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import random


def dorandom(n):
    lst = set(map(int, str(n)))
    if len(lst) > 8 + 1:
        return None
    
    n = random.randrange(8 + 1)
    while n in lst:
        n = random.randrange(8 + 1)
    return n
```

без цикла:

```
import random

def dorandom(n):
    lst0 = set(map(int, str(n)))
    lst1 = set(range(8 + 1))
    try:
        return random.choice(list(lst1 - lst0))
    except IndexError:
        return None
```

короче:

```
def dorandom(n):
    try:
        return random.choice(list(set(range(8 + 1)) - set(map(int, str(n)))))
    except IndexError:
        return None
```

Comment: Вы код то тестировали? )   Первый который. Он не выполняется из-за ошибки, плюс к тому 8 никогда не сгенерится, плюс ещё ошибки есть

Comment: Второй код хороший, но мне кажется 8 надо включить. Хотя надо уточнить у автора

Comment: @CrazyElf исправил)

Answer (score 0):

```
def dorandom(number):
    from random import randint
    while True:
        f = randint(0, 8)
        if f not in str(number):
            return f

print(dorandom(324))
```